# Spring Cloud DataFlow - SpringBoot3 not showing stats of execution

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow

When running Spring DataFlow in kubernetes and deploying docker images I'm not seeing boot3 stats from the execution. I do see the data in the database (in the tables prefixed with `boot3`), but not in the UI.

[image: Example UI]

I have dug around the docs and don't see a way to set boot3 as the default or tell the UI to use the tables.

I haven't found anything in the docs point me to a direction on how to get the UI to show the data for boot3

Comment: What version of SCDF are you currently using?

Comment: Latest `2.11.2`

Comment: I have figured this out. It requires the `@EnableTask` annotation on the springboot3 application class.